# ps -ef + fourfield from ps -ef output

Tags: linux

I need explain about the four field (4 or 0 )  of ps -ef command , what the meaning of this number
THX yael

root     27116 27112  4 15:25 pts/0    00:00:00 grep -qsRw -m1 monitohhhhhhhr /var

root     29017 27113  0 15:25 pts/0    00:00:00 grep qsRw -m1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should be the process flags. From [this page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ps) (the ps man page):

```
The sum of these values is displayed in the "F" column, which is provided by
the flags output specifier.
1    forked but didn't exec
4    used super-user privileges
```

zero, I guess, would be a normal process.

Comment: maybe 0 tell us that proccess isnt alive?

Comment: +1. @yael, more likely that it has not forked at all. Non-alive processes which are yet to have their return code reaped (zombies) will have a process name of something like `<DEFUNCT>`. Non-alive processes which _have_ had their return code reaped won't show up :-)

Answer (score 0):

This information can be found in the manual of ps(1):

```
C        processor utilization. Currently, this is the integer value of the percent usage over the lifetime of the process. (see %cpu)
```

Comment: o value is not alive proccess